# What is better - Mysql vs csv -

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Sorry if this has been ask but i can't find anything about this on the form,

I am making a shipping calculator and i get csv files from my courier with rate and place (the calculator is made in php),my question is - what is best to read the CSV file in as an array or import the CSV to Mysql database and read the data that way?

If anyone has some experience with this type of situation and won't mine telling me the best way to go about this that will be so great.

I have not tried anything because i would like to know what the best way is to go about this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Depends how you want to access the data: if you want direct access to individual records, then a database table with decent indexes will normally be faster than having to load and loop through a csv file; but the frequency with which the file contents change may make a difference to the practicalities of this

Comment: how large is the CVS? i mean rows and columns by that.

Comment: Hi Raymond,You can see in the below comments i said 8000+.have a great one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't this depend upon how many times a day you need to access the data, and how often the shipping data is updated?

eg if the shipping data is updated daily, and you access it 10000 times per day, then yes it would be worth importing it into a db so you can do your lookups.

(this is the kind of job sqlite was designed for btw).

If the shipping data is updated every minute, then you'd be best grabbing it every time.

If the shipping data is updated daily, and you only access it 10 times, then I wouldn't worry too much - either grab it an cache the file then access it as a PHP array.

Sorry, but I am not familiar with the data feed in question.

Comment: Hi Cups,the CSV will be updated once every 2 weeks or so and the access amount depends on the volume of clients we have - this is the first time we are using something like this so we don't know how meny times it will be accessed - But thanks for your answer:)

Comment: Yeah, so essentially you want to cache the file locally in one operation (probably invoked by cron, or when you detect the csv file has changed on their server).  How you then access your locally cached file is the crux of your question - for me using PDO and sqlite is what I would naturally do because of my familiarity with them.  One good feature of sqlite is that it is a not only a db, but is a file on your hdd - so you can just delete it on successfully fetching the next new cached csv file.  Of course a lot may depend on how many rows in the csv file, if only 10 then forget it!

Comment: the CSVs have 8000+ rows - i am new to programming and DB's (mysql..etc) so i will have a look at sqlite - Thanks again.

Comment: So, yes, put it into a db, and yes, you will have to probably learn some SQL - with there being many many more examples of Mysql tutorials, you might be best getting a Mysql version working before delving into sqlite, though its really up to you.

Comment: Thanks Cups i will take your advice - Have a great day!!